# render object sorted after filtering

Tags: javascript, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I am facing issue while trying to display sorted suggestions with react-bootstrap-typeahead.

JSON

```
{
  "Code": "ABC",
  "Name": "Random City, Town Office (ABC), Random Country",
  "CityName": "Random City",
  "CityCode": "ABC",
  "CountryName": "Random Country",
  "CountryCode": "XY",
  "Field": "Town Office"
},
{
  "Code": "CBA",
  "Name": "Random City, Town Office (CBA), Random Country",
  "CityName": "City",
  "CityCode": "CBA",
  "CountryName": "Country",
  "CountryCode": "CC",
  "Field": "Town Office"
}
```

The desired output should be searched by city alphabetically if it matches, if not should search for country name and then the output rendered should be sorted alphabetically.

I tried pushing callback data from typeahead's *filterBy* to an array and sorting it, but, since JSON from service is not sorted and callback data is random, unable to achieve the same.

Is there any other way to achieve the same?

```
<Typeahead
  {...this.state.typeProps}
  labelKey="Name"
  placeholder="Enter Origin..."
  bsSize="large"
  onChange={(selected) => {
    this.setState({ selected });
  }}
  filterBy={(option, props) => {
    if (this.filterAndPush(option, props)) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }}
                }}
  options={this.state.originData}
  selected={this.state.selected}
/>

filterData = (option, props) => {
  const { text } = props;
  const { CityName, CityCode } = option;
  if (text) {
    if (CityName.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())) {
      return true;
    } else if (CityCode.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}

filterAndPush = (option, props) => {
  //debugger;
  if (this.filterData(option, props)) {
    debugger;
    this.filterResultSet.push(option);
    this.filterResultSet.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.CityName < b.CityName)
        return -1;
      if (a.CityName > b.CityName)
        return 1;
      return 0;
    });
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can sort your data:

1) **Pre-sort the options** before passing them into the `options` prop. Given your scenario, this is probably the easiest approach. In your `render` method, simply do the following:

```
const options = this.state.originData.sort(sortCallback);

return (
  <Typeahead
    ...
    options={options}
  />
);
```

2) **Sort the filtered results** using `renderMenu`. [Check out the custom menu example](http://ericgio.github.io/react-bootstrap-typeahead/#rendering) to see this in action. Basically, you can pass a callback that receives the filtered results and render them however you want:

```
_renderMenu(results, menuProps) {
  const items = results.sort(sortCallback);

  return (
    <Menu {...menuProps}>
      {items.map((item, index) => {
        <MenuItem key={index} option={item} position={index}>
          {...}
        </MenuItem>
      })}
    </Menu>
  );
}


render() {
  return (
    <Typeahead
      ...
      renderMenu={this._renderMenu}
    />
  );
}
```